# How to prove this logarithmic function?

Tags: logarithms

\begin{equation}
-\log\left(\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}\right)
\end{equation}

You are not given the R.H.S . How to prove this?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Please type your question in MathJax formatting. It is rather difficult to read.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to do that yet. Can you help?

Comment: I just did it for you, check this https://www.mathjax.org/ next time. Also, tell us what you have tried if you want to get rid of the downvotes.

Comment: I don't have any idea rn. Yeah I saw that you edited it. Thank You!

Comment: I just took some terms from RHS to LHS and they did become equal so the equality holds but I didn't post this because it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

By the rules for logarithms we have $-\log(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x})=\log(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1})=\log((\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}})=\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)^2})$. Now we simplify and use a little trick: $\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)^2})=\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{1+x^2-1}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)^2})=\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)(\sqrt{1+x^2}+1)}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-1)^2})=\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1})$.

Comment: Yeah I did till that last first step and got stuck. I didn't get the idea of +1 -1. Thank You!

Comment: If you think this answers your question, please accept it to show that to others.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{blue}{\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2} + 1}{\sqrt{1+x^2} + 1} = \color{blue}{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2} + 1}}$

Now if we square $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}$, we can get rid of $x$

$\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\right)^2 =\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2} + 1} =\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}$

$\Rightarrow2\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\right) = \ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}\right)$

or

$-\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}\right) = -\frac12\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}\right) = \frac12\ln\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x^2}+1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}\right)$